# RenderBody not rendering my views

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi Im working on a site with a boostrap template. What i want is that when the user click a link, it would call a controller function return a view and focus to the body section.

To do that I have _Layout with my render body function

```
<section id="bodySection">
@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And a href that calls a funciton and focus on the body

```
  <a href="#bodySection" onclick="myFunction()">Education</a>
```

my function the fires on the onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        //alert("I am an alert box!");
        $.post("@Url.Action("Education", "Education")");
        }
</script>
```

And my controler

```
    public ActionResult Education()
    {
       {...........}
        return View();
    }
```

When I press the button the focus go to the body section, the controller is called but the body section remains with the old view. If I inspect the page i dont get any error. 
Can somebody tell me what is going on with my code please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not work because the  tag is just an anchor link, it only scrolls the page to the point where #bodySection is and executes a $.post to a service that returns a certain result, but doesn't redirect to the new page.

I would change your link to:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Education", "Education")">Education</a>
```

Then add the following script to the view in order to make the page automatically smooth-scroll to the anchor point every time on load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bodySection").offset().top
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wanted to do a smooth scroll , i tried this

 anchor.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });

But it only works good on firefox. 

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: YEAH! That is what i needed, i tried this before but somehow it didn't work, just one question, is there a way to do the same for all views without writing this last piece of code in all the views?

Comment: Well yes of course, include that script in the _layout itself and that will be it (but only if you're sure what all the views will have the target section with id "bodySection", otherwise the console will throw an exception